# Can the server I upload and download files to with filezilla see my desktop and files?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I upload and download files from my desktop to a server for work using filezilla. I am wondering if the server can see the files on my desktop when I upload? I don't just mean the files I upload from my desktop which it can obviously see, but also the files on my desktop that I choose not to upload e.g. word documents.

Can the server see the filenames or files on my desktop that I choose not to upload? Similarly can the server see my computer when I download from the server onto my desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP (assuming that's the protocol you're using with FileZilla) only defines the transfer of files from your computer to the server. The server never sees your local files unless you upload them — FileZilla simply presents both views to you as part of its GUI.

Comment: Nailed it - Check out Wiki for rules and a better overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

Servers, being naturally curious creatures, will occasionally take a little look-see at your desktop. Especially if you have word docs with saucy-sounding names. They're also known to be overly critical of your wallpaper.
What you should be more concerned about are routers, the desktop vandals of the hardware world. If I had a nickel for every time ive come back to my computer to find "for a good time, call 192.168.1.1" scrawled across my desktop, I'd be a very wealthy man.

Comment: If you choose not to believe me I understand, but when it happens to you, don't say I didn't warn you. Now if you'll excuse me, I must be going, my AirPort is snooping through my photos again. I must reprimand it.